# openXML overwrites formated cell in template

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a formated template stored in the Database.

after building and opening the Excel the cell has the format but its not formated like it should. 
example: the field looks in the template like this. 1234.56$ but know it is looking like this 1234.56. so the $ is missing. 
second example. 12% its looking like but know its looking like this 11.9999999997%

The value I put in are exact values. like 1234.56 and 11.9999999997% so if i put them manually in the generatet excle it worsk with the formating but not during the creating phase.

does anyone have some ideas?

My insert statment

```
public static void InsertRows(List<ExcelRow> rowDefinitions, Stream template, string sheetName)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(template, true))
        {
            // tell Excel to recalculate formulas next time it opens the doc
            doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
            doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;

            foreach (var rd in rowDefinitions)
            {
                // first get the context (WS + SheetData)
                var ws = GetWorksheetPart(doc.WorkbookPart, sheetName);
                var sheetData = ws.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().First();


                var nr = CreateRow((uint)rd.RowIndex, sheetData);

                foreach (var cd in rd.Cells)
                {
                    var c = EnsureCell(nr, cd.ColumnName);
                    SetCellValue(cd.CellText, c, doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart);
                }
            }
            doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify your number format? As in https://documentation.devexpress.com/#DocumentServer/CustomDocument12273 ?